# Sqlite: conditionally query two tables, one will not exist

Tags: sqlite

I am sure I can solve this programmatically, but I am curious if I can do this in one query.

Context:

I will be querying multiple databases, some will have a table; 'table', others will instead have the table; 'table_v2'. I want to run the same SELECT statement on the table that exists. I know I can check if a table exists, but I want to know if I can do it all in one statement.

psuedo code summary of what I want to do in **one statement**:

```
if 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=''table'; is not empty:
     SELECT * FROM table;
else 
     SELECT * FROM table_v2;
```

I am beholden to constraints out of my control.

Thoughts:

1. Could I have the table name be a regex?
2. Can I run both SELECTS, ignore the failed result, and just return the success?

Comment: Can you create a view name table in the second database which return data from table_v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't do either.  The query planner in SQLite needs to know the name of the table beforehand, and it must be valid so it can determine which paths to take.

You can use the [loadable extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) [`eval`](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/eval.c) to build up the SQL query based off of the schema.  Though, this exposes a variant of the same issue, since the query planner needs the table name, you need to build up the entire SQL statement, then run it, so you'll need two `eval` calls.

```
SELECT EVAL(
    'SELECT * FROM ''' || 
    EVAL('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=''table'' AND name IN (''table'', ''table_v2'');') || 
    ''';'
);
```

To use the `eval` function, you'll need to either build and load the extension as a library, or build it into your own custom build of SQLite itself.

Of course, I can't answer if you *should* do this.